# Does OpenXML SDK only work with Visual Studio?

Tags: python-3.x, django, iis, openxml-sdk

I am creating a Django application to be run on an IIS server.

I need to update an Excel file automatically on the server. Given that the interactive update using COM (pywin32.com) is not supported by Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) I need to use the Microsoft recommended approach which involves using OpenXML SDK.

In the following link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/getting-started, it mentions this is used with Visual Studio.

My question is whether this is the only way of using OpenXML SDK to edit Office documents.

I do not use Visual Studio.

Thank you for any help provided

I have searched the internet but have not found a suitable answer.

Comment: Microsoft only published the Open XML specification and .NET implementation. Your Python web app can use none of those. While some Python developers have their own implementations (open source or commercial), such as https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, it is up to your own judgement whether to rely on them or cook your own. Such information is widely available on search engines, but "suitable" or not is subjective. Asking for recommendations is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: At present, it seems that Microsoft's use of the OpenXML SDK is only based on the .net implementation method. And you can refer to the link provided by Lex Li in the comment.